# How can get current viewport sizes in scss?

Tags: css, sass, viewport

I want to get current devices viewport size.

Is can get current devices viewport size in scss?

Comment: It looks like the *"scss"* is [Viewports project](https://github.com/jareware/viewports), a.k.a. *"_viewports.scss"*.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, You can set a CSS value of a CSS property using viewport-related [CSS units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).